# Programmatically turn off the automation features of windows speech recognition?

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition

I'm making a program that uses the system.speech namespace (it's a simple program that will launch movies). I load all of the filenames from a folder and add them to the grammars I want to use. It's working remarkably well, however there is a hitch: I DON'T want the windows speech recognition to interact with windows at all (ie. when I say start, I don't want the start menu to open... I don't want anything to happen).

Likewise, I have a listbox for the moment that lists all of the movies found in the directory. When I say the show/movie that I want to open, the program isn't recognizing that the name was said because windows speech recognition is selecting the listboxitem from the list instead of passing that to my program.

The recognition is working otherwise, because I have words like "stop", "play", "rewind" in the grammar, and when I catch listener_SpeechRecognized, it will correctly know the word(s)/phrase that I'm saying (and currently just type it in a textbox).

Any idea how I might be able to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the [SpeechRecognitionEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.aspx) class rather than the SpeechRecognizer class.  This creates a speech recognizer that is completely disconnected from Windows Speech Recognition.

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool Status = false;

SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
Choices dic = new Choices(new String[] {
            "word1",
            "word2",
            });



public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Grammar gmr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(dic));
    gmr.Name = "myGMR";
    // My Dic

    sre.LoadGrammar(gmr);
  sre.SpeechRecognized += 
  new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);
    sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
    sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
} 

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Status)
    {
        button1.Text = "START";
        Status = false;
        stslable.Text = "Stopped";
    }
    else {

        button1.Text = "STOP";
        Status = true;
        stslable.Text = "Started";
    }
}

public void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs ev)
{
   String theText = ev.Result.Text;
  MessageBox.Show(theText);
}
```